# Feature to Add a Site (web) based on Team Site

Tags: feature, publishing-site

Is there a good link that can show how to add a sub-site under the existing site collection based on "Team Site" (STS#0) Template? (the sitecollection url is http://local/sites/Amtrack). The url for sub site is going to be then http://local/sites/Amtrack/newSubsite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link has a good code example for creating a site from a Site Definition:

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-5-Programatically_create_a_SharePoint_site_based_on_a_site_definition.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I was on the same page. I guess, I will feature with receiver and kick start the code on feature activation.